One at a time async in F#?
What is a good approach to wrapping an Async<'t> such that only one of them can run at a time?
I have come up with a solution using MailboxProcessor although I wonder if a more lightweight mechanism is possible.
open System
open System.Threading.Tasks

let oneAtATime (workflow : Async<'t>) =
  let rec logic (taskCache : Task<'t> option) (inbox : MailboxProcessor<AsyncReplyChannel<Task<'t>>>) =
    async {
      let! channel = inbox.Receive()

      match taskCache with
      | Some task when not task.IsCompleted ->
        channel.Reply(task)

        return! logic taskCache inbox
      | _ ->
        let task = Async.StartAsTask workflow

        channel.Reply(task)

        return! logic (Some task) inbox
    }

  let actor = MailboxProcessor.Start(logic None)

  async {
    let! t = actor.PostAndAsyncReply(id)

    return! Async.AwaitTask t
  }


I suggest you look here for a possible solution: https://www.fssnip.net/authors/Tomas+Petricek

Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? When you say "only one of them can run at a time", what do you mean by "them"? For example, are you saying that if you have an Async<int> and an Async<string>, you want this mechanism to force them to run in series? If so, have you considered using a simple lock?

suggest adding some more context about whether you want one per process, and/or any retrying/caching semantics etc, as that can be a significant factor (i.e. my answer has two approaches, but there are about 3 more I have in mind and/or use In the Propulsion library, but as it stands I assuem they are not relevant)

Like this:
type System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim with

    /// Wait for capacity to be available. Returns false if timeout elapsed before this as achieved
    member semaphore.Await(timeout: TimeSpan): Async<bool> = async {
        let! ct = Async.CancellationToken
        return! semaphore.WaitAsync(timeout, ct) |> Async.AwaitTaskCorrect
    }

    /// Wait indefinitely for capacity to be available on the semaphore
    member semaphore.Await(): Async<unit> = async {
        let! ct = Async.CancellationToken
        return! semaphore.WaitAsync(ct) |> Async.AwaitTaskCorrect
    }

    /// Throttling wrapper that waits asynchronously until the semaphore has available capacity
    member semaphore.Throttle(workflow: Async<'T>): Async<'T> = async {
        do! semaphore.Await()
        try return! workflow
        finally semaphore.Release() |> ignore

If your desired DOP is 1, then  you:
let limiter = new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(1)
Seq.replicate 5 asyncThing |> Seq.map limiter.Throttle |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously

^ the asyncThing body executions will be serialized, limited by the fact that any execution will be bracketed by Obtaining/Releasing the semaphore. If you only ever need exactly one, you can of course do the same thing with an even lighter weight lock primitive than a Semaphore.
(Obviously you can also do that via  Seq.replicate 5 asyncThing |> Async.Sequential |> Async.RunSynchronously, but I trust that sort of limiting is what you're after)
(Depending on what you're really doing, there's also a TaskCell in Equinox.Core (see usage examples in the tests))

I think you can just use a for loop:
async {
    for item in 1..10 do
        do! Async.Sleep 1000
        printfn $"item: {item}"
}

